Musixtex bgroup command not working with musixlyr
It is needed to split in two columns (with additional space between those columns) using Musixtex bgroup command together with musixlyr. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={8pt -10pt 12pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=1.0\linewidth%
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{\B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{{6} {4}}} \B V}%
\setlyrics{AcordesB}{\B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{{6} {4}}} \B V}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.1cm}
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\interstaff{7}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
%\stafftopmarg0pt\staffbotmarg5\Interligne\relax%
\setclef16
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
\hbox to\hsize\bgroup\vbox\bgroup\hsize=3.7cm%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{Acordes}
\notes\hsk\wh{G}|\hsk\wh{g}\en
\lyricsoff
\notes\hsk|\hsk\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\endpiece%
\egroup\hfill\vbox\bgroup\hsize=3.7cm%       
\resetlyrics
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{AcordesB}
\notes\hsk\wh{G}|\hsk\wh{g}\en%
\lyricsoff%
\notes\hsk|\hsk\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\endpiece%
\egroup\egroup%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

The desired output shuld be:

Note: The target is to use only one music environment.

Solved:
\documentclass[%
border={8pt -10pt 17.5pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=1.0\linewidth%
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{\B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{{6} {4}}} \B V}%
\setlyrics{AcordesB}{\B K\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{{6} {4}}} \B V}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.1cm}
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\interstaff{7}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
%\stafftopmarg0pt\staffbotmarg5\Interligne\relax%
\setclef16
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
\hbox to\hsize\bgroup\vbox\bgroup\hsize=0.48\textwidth%4.7cm%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{Acordes}
\notes\hsk\wh{G}|\hsk\wh{g}\en
\lyricsoff
\notes\hsk|\hsk\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\endpiece%
\egroup\hfill\hspace{1.0cm}\vbox\bgroup\hsize=0.48\textwidth%4.7cm%       
\resetlyrics
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{AcordesB}
\notes\hsk\wh{G}|\hsk\wh{g}\en%
\lyricsoff%
\notes\hsk|\hsk\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\endpiece%
\egroup\egroup%
\end{music}
\end{document}

Just adjust: \hsize=0.48\textwidth, and \hfill\hspace{1.0cm}.
The output is as follow:


Why do you ask a question, when you can answer it yourself?

Hi Peters, at that moment I didnt know the solution... Trying and testing help me solving the problem and share it to the foro team ... Regards
